# How to route siblings grand child in angular 2 router

Tags: angular2-routing

My router code is as below. When I am trying to access intro page in DashboardComponent, 
it loads intro component but comes back to dashboard, what am I doing wrong?

```
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent,         //home component
    children: [
     { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent } // first child
     { path: 'main', component: ClientComponent,          //2nd child
         children: [
                { path:'intro', component:ClientsComponent, outlet:intro',
                  children: [  // grand children
                    { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
                    { path: 'list', component: ListComponent},                
                  ]
                },
         ]}
     }
```

I tried with both navigate and navigateByUrl, none seems to work:

router.navigate(['../main', {outlets: {'intro': ['intro']}}], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute}) 
                            OR
router.navigateByUrl('main/(intro:intro/list)');

Comment: try this router.navigate(['./main', {outlets: {'intro': ['intro']}}], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})

Comment: If we give ./main, it will route to dashboard/main and again which is not what we want.

Comment: try this router.navigate(['./main/intro', {outlets: {'intro': ['intro']}}], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute})